# Why the pgfplots give a wrong plot?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot this function but apparently get wrong plots at high x regions. What mistakes I made?

```
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\def\distance{1cm}%
\vspace{\distance}
\def\distance{2cm}%
\hspace{\distance}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines=
    {circle, magnification=6, connect spies}]
\begin{loglogaxis}[xlabel=$T$, ymin=1e0,ymax=1e8,
ylabel=$H_{0}$,domain={10^-2:10^8} ]

\addplot[blue,thick,samples=500,domain=10^-2:10^8]{x*(exp(10/x)-1)};

\legend {Body centered cubic}

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the plot I have:
 [image]

Comment: TeX's mathematical capabilities are limited (precision/time). Sometimes, it is easier to do the calculations externally and to include the calculated coordinates as data file in the plot for `pgfplots`.

Comment: try with `gnuplot`, for example `\addplot gnuplot[-,blue,thick,samples=500,domain=10e-2:10e8]{x*(exp(10/x)-1)};` and run with `shell-escape` ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It finally works. Gnuplot seems to be the best option.

Comment: @TianHao glad you have a solution :) would you like to self-answer with what you did?

Comment: @cmhughes I exactly follow  what you had suggested earlier: use \addplot gnuplot and run with shell-escape. Then I got the straight lines at high x regions. My another question: can we trust the calculation from pgfplots? Why they generate such erratic shape of lines at certain regions?  Thank you very much again!

Comment: @TianHao Yes we can trust the calculations from pgfplots, as long we know what we are doing (i.e., what calculations require better precision). For the spikes at the end of the plot, you might want to look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). I think this the is problem here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.